# Update Root Site Collection Template

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, hub-site, root

I want to create a "Hub" in SharePoint Online, and have it as the root Site collection for our tenant. I believe it's recommended to have this site collection be a "Communication" site, but right now it's a classic team site.

Is there a way to change which site collection is the Root site collection? If it is, is it possible to keep the original site collection (or at least its data) in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are asking about the Site Collection swapping features. It is possible but feature is not rolled out yet. Last Week SharePoint Conference, Microsoft announced it and will be available by end of this year.

Check this blog and search for Site swap. [SharePoint Site Swap (Coming Soon)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Updates-to-SharePoint-security-administration-and-migration/ba-p/549585)

But you can change the Root site collection to Modern Communication site using the following command: `[Enable-SPOCommSite][2]` Can be used to transform existing classic team site from the root site collection of a tenant as a communication site

You can also make the root site collection as your hub site as well, via SharePoint admin center.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It doesn't appear to be available for my tenant yet, however... I get the "*The requested operation is part of an experimental feature that...*". How are you supposed to enable the experimental features for SharePoint Online PowerShell?

Comment: you have to opt for the target release: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Enable-Targeted-Release-in-Office-365-to-receive-updates-first/td-p/135052

Comment: Thanks. Our change management process won't allow us to do this as of yet, but I'll keep it in mind for when we are able to.